# Why model performs poor after normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm using fully connected neural network and I am using normalized data such that every single sample values range from 0 to 1. I have used 100 neurons in first layer and 10 in second layer and used almost 50 lack samples during training. I want to classify my data into two classes. But my networks performance is too low, almost 49 percent on training and test data. I tried to increase the performance by changing the values of hyper parameters. But it didn't work. Can some one please tell me what should I do to get higher performance?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nPixels])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nPixels, nNodes1], stddev=0.01))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nNodes1]))
y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nNodes1, nNodes2], stddev=0.01))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nNodes2]))
y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nNodes2, nLabels], stddev=0.01))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nLabels]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y2, W3) + b3)

y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

cross_entropy = -1*tf.reduce_sum(y_* tf.log(y), axis=1)    
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,axis=1), tf.argmax(y, axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
```

Comment: The title of your question suggests that it was working before you did 'normalization'. Could you be specific on what has changed?

Comment: Yes my model was giving 98 percent accuracy without normalization. I have performed normalization on the input data having shape (samples,features). I have normalized the feature of every sample such that in each single sample feature ranges from 0 to one. This is the only change that I have made in input data. After this accuracy suddenly drops. I want to improve performance after normalization

Comment: What is the variance of your data?

Comment: I didn't check the variance. Should I check it for each sample? Why we nned variance if I normalize each sample from 0 to 1?

Comment: If the performance was 98% anyway, why would you change anything?

Comment: I want to reduce some information to make it complicated .Just want to see how machine behaves

Comment: Normalization -- if we speak of range normalization -- does not reduce any information (unless you run into numeric issues). It is a trivially invertible operation.

Answer (score 3):

Your computational model knows nothing about "images", it only sees numbers. So if you trained it with pixels of values from 0-255, it has learned what "light" means, what "dark" means and how do these combine to give you whatever target value you try model.

And what you did by the normalization is that you forced all pixel to be 0-1. So as far as the model cares, they are all black as night. No surprise that it cannot extract anything meaningful.

**You need to apply the same input normalization during both training and testing.**

And speaking about normalization for NN models, it is better to normalize to zero mean.

Comment: I have applied this normalization to both training and test set. Suppose my input values in one sample were -4 to +4 so by normalization I shifted them on a different scale 0 to 1. Why should I expect that machine can not extract any information. I even tried to make model complex by adding different layers and provided more data but still there is no improvement in accuracy. I'm bound to implement min max normalization.

Comment: But have you trained the model with the normalized values? From reading your comment under the question, I got the idea that you have not.

Comment: Yes I trained the model with normalized values. Above code that I have mentioned  contains two hidden layer. I varied number of neurons ,and also added a large amount of data. But still performance is too low. I was wondering how to improve it

Comment: Hey, that changes things, you should have said that ;-) But really, try to normalize them to zero mean, e.g. to <-1; 1> (and check the distribution, there may be outliers screwing the min-max normalization heavily). Also, for such a small network, `tanh` can be expected to work better than `relu`. And finally, learning rate tuning typically gives you the most. Try lowering it geometrically. Do changes one by one.

Comment: if i normalize b/w -1 and 1 is is similar to 0 to 1 means shifting a scale. Why should I expect that in this case network will perform better?

Comment: I also wan to mention that my values in each sample already lie in -4 t0 4 means mean is zero. So if I change it to -1 to 1 there is no significant compression of input data

Comment: See the classic http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf, Section 4.3.
In general, input normalization matters just as much as weight initialization. (D)NNs are not at all mean/var invariant, unless you explicitly make them so through some *norm.

Comment: How do achieve this "compression"? I'd expect that the inputs are 32-bit float anyway, so you just decrease the exponent by two.... Note that it should perhaps be mentioned in your original question so that anybody trying to reply has the info on your ultimate goal in mind.